# Rewrite URL dynamic multipage product woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, woocommerce

this question might be stupid but i tried everything. Or at least close to everything...

I want to have multiple url for 1 product page. And by that i mean i want a different for url for different part of the content let me explain :

This is the basic url :  mysite.com/product/product-name/

I want the description here : mysite.com/product/product-name/description

Or the reviews here : mysite.com/product/product-name/reviews

For now i have mysite.com/product/product-name/?page=description or mysite.com/product/product-name/?page=reviews.

I have the basic permalinks wordpress settings :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ticketbroadway/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ticketbroadway/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using woocommerce.

If any of you could help me, im reallly bad with regex, url rewriting  and htaccess... Thanks in advance.

Comment: No question involving modrewrite or regex is stupid, because that stuff is straight up voodoo. I'm intrigued by this question, but I don't really have much of an idea how to do it. Maybe [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ticketbroadway/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2/?page=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ticketbroadway/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Actually i realised if i go to mysite.com/product/product-name/reviews it shows a 404 error (server 404 page not my site 404 error...) Any idea why ?